# Error : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon')

Tags: android, eclipse

Error : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').

This is my manifest... I'm extremely new to this, just started this morning and have no previous programming experience.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.asdf"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 </application>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
<activity android:name="ExampleActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove this : 
 </application>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

Comment: Please do not duplicate [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796761/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-dr).

Answer (score 47):

Found this question. I was importing an old project into android studio and got the error.

The issue was eventually answered for me here [mipmap drawables for icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons)

In the manifest it has

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
...
```

but @drawable has been superseded by @mipmap so needed changing to:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
...
```

I put this answer here, as it may become a more common issue.

Comment: Worked for Xamarin.Android too!

Answer (score 19):

What solved the problem for me was - create a folder "drawable" in "..platforms/android/res/" and put "icon.png" in it.

Comment: this solution works for me when I use cordova. For anyone who is experiencing this problem while using Apache Cordova (or any of its children like Phonegap, Ionic, etc) should refer to this answer.

Comment: This was almost it. I needed it inside  res/mipmap/icon.png

Comment: helped even in Xamrain

Comment: I had to add ic_launcher.png not icon.png

Answer (score 6):

If you are 100% sure that directories and files are ok, have a look at the project location.

There is a limit on the path length of files in the Operating System. Perhaps this limit is being exceded in your project files.

**Move the project to a shorter folder (say C:/MyProject) and try again!**

This was the problem for me!

Comment: You are a champion. Thanks.

Comment: I was saving my project files a few levels within my OneDrive folder. Moving them up a few levels worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've spent on this problem much time and as for me (**for Intellij IDEA**) the solution is to *specify right path to res directory*:

- right click on project
- click Modules in the left panel
- select Android below your project name
- in Structure tab set right path.

And don't forget to **check all the paths in this tab**!

I hope it will be helpful for somebody!

Comment: This was it for me - or actually, in my case (as I work from CLI) I had to add `res.srcDirs = ['res']` to `android { sourceSets { main {` in my `build.gradle`

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line from your manifest:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

You have two application tags only one should be present.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still same error :/ unless I need to restart Eclipse instead of just refresh?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **icon.png** through visual.

`Resouces... / Dravable/ Add ///`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Googlemare Landmine....
Somehow, if you mess up, the icon line on your .gen file dies. (Empirical proof of mine after struggling 2 hours)

Insert a new icon 72x72 icon on the hdpi folder with a different name from the original, and update the name on the manifest also.

The icon somehow resurrects on the Gen file and voila!! time to move on.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have previously changed your icon or the ic_launcher; and when that ic_launcher no longer exists in your base folder.

Try adding a png image and giving the same name and then copy it to your drawable folder.Now re build the project.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem. i created a picture for my background with jpg format. before added this picture, i changed the format to png with rename the format. and then i got this error like you. i changed my format picture with picture editor like photoshop to png and replaced it with picture in my project and then i hadnt that error. sory for bad english

Answer (score 0):

if cordova app
copy a valid png file to

resources\android\icon.png

and then run

ionic resources --icon

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use Xamarin with Visual Studio 2013. I create Blank App (Android) then deploy without any code update.

You can try:

- Make sure that icon.png (or whatever files mentioned in the application android:icon tag) is present in the drawable-hdpi folder inside res folder of Android project.
- If it shows the error even if the icon.png is present,then remove the statement application android:icon from the AndroidManifest.xml and add it again.
- Check your project folder's path. If it is too long, or contains space, or contains any unicode character, try to relocated.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to build HelloWorld app on Ubuntu 16.04. Got error with drawable/icon. Solution could be:

```
cp ./platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/25.3.1/res/drawable/navigation_empty_icon.xml    ./platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/25.3.1/res/drawable/icon.xml
```

So, it look like icon.xml file missed.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error. I have a Cordova application and the problem was that in `config.xml` I had a duplicated element `<icon src="icon.png">`, one pointing to an non-existing path.

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler solution - delete the cache folder at user/.android/built-cache and go back to android studio and sync with gradle again, if that still doesn't work delete the cache folder again, and restart android studio and re-import the project