# Receiving an error within Google Play Library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-play-services

I am new to eclipse and receiving this error

error: no resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled').

Here is my common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal" />
</selector>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case of missing files. You are using a drawable image/resource that doesn't exist. Go to your drawable folder and make sure you have those png (PNGs are normally used for buttons)images namely: common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.png, common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.png, etc.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796761/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-dr), although not exactly same, may offer insight.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, files were probably missing in the library because i was able to upload a newer version of google play services library and worked perfect.