# Resources missing at AndroidLauncher

Tags: android, libgdx

I was in the middle of adding some Facebook sdk methods when AndroidLauncher class starting giving me errors out of no where.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable-hdpi/i_launcher" android:label="@string/appname" android:theme="@style/GdxTheme">
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/appname" android:name="com.progrmor.tombstone.android.AndroidLauncher" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable-hdpi/i_launcher').**

and:
 Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/appname')

for example.

I´ve checked in Androi->res and there are 4 folders named drawable-hdpi etc, containing i_launcher.png And the string missing is also contained inside values folder.

What is happening? Im going mad about this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: many times I can promise you

Comment: Try removing the -hdpi extension when specifing the icon location in the manifest.

Comment: rere252 , tried already.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796414/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-dr

Comment: Didn´t help either? I changed in both AndroidLauncher and Manifest to "@mipmap/i_launcher"

Comment: Take a look at the other answers provided there also.

Comment: should I put mimap infront of strings and styles aswell? And should I rename the folders themself to mimap aswell?

Comment: I´ve narrowed it down. Error says "(at 'label' with value '@strings/app_name')" It´s looking for app_name in the facebook project. Why would my manifest look for resources in another project?