# Image icon not working?

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, android-studio

For some reason, my image icon is getting an error, despite all of my attempts to fix it...

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796414/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-dr) question where the answer suggests to make the image icon in the mitmap folder. So, I changed the line of code that I had from `@drawable/myImage` to `@mitmap/ic_launcher`

[image]

You can see that there is an error on the image. Why could this be?

I have tried to:

- **Clean project**
- **Rebuild project**
- **Made sure @mitmap/ic_launcher actually exists:**

[image]

The error still persists, even after all of my attempts. I have been stuck on this for multiple hours, and I cant get my head around it. Is it a problem with my code, or android studio? I would really appreciate all of your help!

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your manifest file, change **@mitmap** to **@mipmap**. That's the correct directory name.

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: WOW! I spent all day for one stupid little typo... Thanks so much for your answer, I have liked and marked you best answer!

Comment: You're welcome, haha... it happens to the best, trust me !

Answer (score 0):

Your folder name is `mipmap` and you are using `mitmap`.