# Icon error building Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-manifest

Using `cordova build` on a one-year-old project raises:

```
:processDebugResources
my_project/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').
```

And then crushes:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem and I solved this by re generating icon paths,
try this

```
ionic resources --icon
```

after this use below command

```
ionic build
```

Comment: you have to add that the should be a valid icon.png in the resources/ folder. For some reason mine was gone and this didn't work for me initially

Comment: Yes you have to add icon file with the name of "icon" in the resource folder before running above command, icon file can be in icon.psd ,png or other common image format.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, does it have:

```
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

If so, you can try switching it to:

```
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

It seems that @drawable has been superseded by @minimap. More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935810/mipmap-drawables-for-icons) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28962245/643779).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not `drawable/ic_launcher` but `drawable/icon`. BTW the manifest was created by `cordova platform add android`.

Comment: did not work and even caused the app to crash after fixed

Comment: This was the solution for me as well.  A project that was updated from pre CLI 6.0 to CLI 6.4 and Android platform 6.1.2.  Had "@drawable/icon" and switching to mipmap cleared the build issue and the app installed and is running normally.

Answer (score 1):

There is debug option `-d` in the cli run the below command to check what is the problem,

```
cordova -d --stacktrace build android
```

Answer (score 0):

copy valid png to
resources\android\icon.png

and then run

ionic resources --icon