# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background')

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

I found the source of my error is in my external library "play-service-base-10.2.1", where it contains a file with the matching name. I'm completely new to android programming, got to this point with my little programming experience.

Here is my android manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.application"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > 
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796414/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-dr