# ionic2 build apk @mipmap/icon error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

i am able to build the apk in android@6.1.2, but when i want do `ionic add platform android@4.4.2`and run `ionic build android` the console outputs

> C:\Users\
>   ...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\armv7\debug\xml\authenticator.xml:2:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon'
>   with value '@mipmap/icon').
>
> C:\Users\
>   ...\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\armv7\debug\xml\authenticator.xml:2:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'smallIcon' with value '@mipmap/icon').

no idea how to fix it and googling/searching stackoverflow didn't help me...

Comment: try this ionic platform add android@5.2.0

Comment: same exception...

Comment: did you add crosswalk plugin ?

Comment: yes i added this plugin...is typed `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` and then `ionic build android`, thats the way to to it isnt it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796414/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-icon-with-value-dr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check icon's are available or not in mipmap folder, and also check config.xml file.

Comment: the mipmap folders all contain ic_launcher.png, so i guess its an naming issue? what should i check my config.xml for? im very new to android...

Comment: check entries of mipmap files in config file.

Comment: ok thats it, now i get another error reffering to gmaps, so i guess this solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is an error as a result of differences in the name in the AndroidManifest.xml
To resolve this

1. Go to Android
2. Click on app
3. Click on src
4. Click on main
5. Click on res
6. Open AndroidManifest.xml
7. Edit the  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"> to the png file name for your icon
   For example:
   if your icon file name is potato.png,
   you will edit the android icon to
   android:icon="@mipmap/potato">
8. Go to File and click Save All
9. Run the app again